# Custom App Code for Firebase Dynamic Linking

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to integrate *deferred deep linking* in my Android app using Firebase Dynamic Links. The problem that I have with Firebase is that I can't see any option to customize my 'app domain name'.

The domain that firebase generates is something like: `<APP CODE>.app.goo.gl`. The `<APP CODE>` value generated by Firebase is not at all human readable. I want it to be something more human readable, (as it's the link which a user will be sharing), and so I want to customize it.

I see, http://branch.io lets you customize that. Is there a way of doing that in Firebase?

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible with Firebase.

Any particular reason you need to use Dynamic Links instead of [Branch.io](https://branch.io)? (Full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). It's fairly simple to [use the two together](https://blog.branch.io/is-branch-a-replacement-for-firebase-dynamic-links).

Comment: Honestly, I preferred Firebase as _branch_ has way too much flexibility! I was looking for a basic ready to go implementation. Neverthless, I think _branch_ is better at this and I am going to use it in my project.